# iOS : How to copy a pdf/doc file from Mail to my app (in Objective-C)?

Tags: ios, iphone, pdf

For a long time, I thought it was just impossible to upload PDF/DOC files to a server from an application as it is impossible to store this kind of file into an iPhone.

However, I recently used an application making it possible by a little workaround which is still interesting for me :

- First step, go into this app and open the view handling the upload :

[image]

- Then, choose a PDF file into Mail and long press it, which opens a popup :

[image]

- And a tap onto the app icon brings me back to it, with the file ready to be uploaded :

[image]

I guess what happens here is that the URL of the file in Mail is being copy-pasted into the other app as well as the file name, but I have tried to find some information about how to do this and could not find anything related... So I need some help now.

Thank you very much.

**PS :** bonus, programmatically talking I'd like to know how to do it the Objective-C way if possible.

Comment: I suggest to create your app with Share Extension.  That allow to show your app icon in Share Activity View controller and get the file at your application.

Comment: @NitinGohel I am having a look at it right now. Very interesting, but only available in iOS 8 and more, am I right?